# Segmentation fault when releasing a string in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, free

I have a "segmentation fault" error when I try to free the allocated memory of the string pointed from "new_job->jobs_adress" . I've allocated enough memory for my string (even if I allocate far beyond from what I need, I still have this problem), But there is still this error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct job_t {
    pid_t pid;
    time_t creation_time;
    bool stop;
    bool foreground;
    char * jobs_adress;
} Job;

int main() {

    char * jobs_adress = "string";

    /* creating an object of "Job" Type */
    printf("another try");
    Job * new_job = (Job*)malloc(sizeof(new_job));
    if(!new_job) {
        return;
    }

    /* allocating memory for a new string, and copies the old string
      into the new string*/

    int length2=strlen(jobs_adress);
    char * str2 = malloc(length2+1);
    strcpy(str2,jobs_adress);
    new_job->jobs_adress=str2;               

    new_job->pid = 1;
    new_job->creation_time = time(NULL);
    new_job->stop=false;
    new_job->foreground=true;

    free(new_job->jobs_adress);  // <=== the error is here

}
```

Comment: `sizeof(new_job)` is `sizeof(Job*)`. Did you intend to write `*new_job`?

Comment: What do you the value of `sizeof (new_job)` is? Ps you do not cast return value of malloc

Comment: Sorry for the confusion....Iv'e edited so the code will (Hopefully) be clearer/

Comment: also `man strdup`

Comment: As `pm100` has mentioned, 3 lines of code can be removed with the usage of strdup:  new_job->job_address = strdup(jobs_address);

Comment: sizeof(Job) when initializing the Job*. You are allocating only whatever the size of a pointer is on your desktop (mine is 4 bytes running on Visual Studio 32bit, platform dependent). You can say sizeof(*new_job) or sizeof(Job)

Answer (score 8):

```
Job * new_job = (Job*)malloc(sizeof(new_job));
```

On this line, `sizeof(new_job)` is measuring the size of variable `new_job`.

`new_job` has type Pointer, and a pointer is (typically) 4 bytes.
So you allocate 4 bytes.

You *intended* to allocate enough space for a `Job` struct.
The line should've been:

```
Job * new_job = (Job*)malloc(sizeof(Job));
```

Comment: You do not need the cast in C for malloc

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now! You're a life-saver!

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(*new_job))` ... That way, your code won't be wrong if `new_job` points to a different type.

Comment: @EdHeal - Up until this year, when my environment was updated to it's latest revision (an implementation of ANSI C99), I never had any problem with _not_ casting the return of `[m][c][re]alloc(.)`.  Now I get big nasty compiler warnings.  I have to believe, depending on the implementations other are using, they could very well be experiencing the same thing.

Comment: @ryyker:  In C, you do not cast the return value.  In C++, you do.  If you are getting new compiler warnings, it is because you are using a C++ compiler on C-code.

Comment: Typically 4 bytes for a pointer is wrong to say. It is platform dependent is the correct answer.

Comment: @abelenky - Normally I would agree, but seeing is believing.  I do not use a C++ compiler, it is `C99`.  I have been using variations of the same tool for 20 years, and it has been generally very solid.  _At this point  though I think a bug report is in order._  Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @ryyker If you are getting a warning from a C compiler when you don't cast the result of `malloc`, _and_ you definitely did include `stdlib.h`, then yes, that's a bug in the compiler.  But if you _didn't_ include `stdlib.h` then the warning is telling you that you need to fix that.

Comment: (This is _why_ you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc` in C: warnings about invalid conversions might be the only notification you get that you forgot to include `stdlib.h`, and on ABIs where `void *` and `int` are not the same size, that is a catastrophic mistake.)

Comment: @zwol - Hmm.  My environment includes a collection header called `ansi_c.h`, which is supposed to include the typical collection of C header files.  `stdlib.h` may be missing from `ansi_c.h` in most current  implementation.  Thank you.